# Is there a way to override all base defaultProps at once in NativeBase components?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

New to NativeBase and using version `3.4.1`.

We're quickly finding that we prefer the `"xl"` size for icons and text.
Is there an easier way to set all font sizes to `xl` without overriding every single component?

Currently we're following the docs and overriding `defaultProps` like this...

```js
import { extendTheme } from 'native-base';

export const ExtendedNativeBaseTheme = extendTheme({
  
  components: {
    Button: {
      defaultProps: {
        size: 'xl',
      },
    },
    Checkbox: {
      defaultProps: {
        _text: {
          fontSize: 'xl',
        },
      },
    },
    Input: {
      defaultProps: {
        size: 'xl',
      },
    },
    Icon: {
      defaultProps: {
        size: 'xl',
      },
    },
    IconButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        _icon: {
          size: 'xl',
        },
      },
    },
    Text: {
      defaultProps: {
        fontSize: 'xl',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [withDefaultSize Theme Extension](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theming/customize-theme#theme-extension-withdefaultsize) is what you want.

Modifying the example from their docs:

```
import { extendTheme, withDefaultSize } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const customTheme = extendTheme(
  withDefaultSize({
    size: 'xl',
    components: ['Button', 'Checkbox', 'Icon', ...],
  }),
)
```

All you would need to do is to list all components that need size `xl` in the `components` property